# python resize image without losing sharpness

Tags: image, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
image = Image.open(sys.argv[1])

basewidth = 1200
img = image
wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), Image.BICUBIC)
img.save('sompic1.jpg')

print "image to %s" % (str(img.size))
```

i want to resize 1200xauto and this without losing any ratio so the image must keep its shartness etc etc.

but resized images are somehow destroyed in sharpness. I used `ANTIALIAS` also, but no change. how is it possible not to lose the sharpness?

original image: (600x450)

[image]

new one (1200x630):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to resize an image to a larger size than the original, it is normal that you loose quality.

To resize you image to a smaller size, you may have a look at this module I created: [python-image-resize](https://github.com/charlesthk/python-resize-image)

Comment: But in this the quality is lost during the resize